# Presenting NSViewController in MacOS app works fine until I archive the build

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsviewcontroller

After an App Store rejection for a MacOS app, i've come across a very strange thing happening.
I have an `NSViewController` in my storyboard with a `storyboardID` set.
I call this from a button with the following code:

```
NSViewController *loginViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateControllerWithIdentifier:@"login"];
[self presentViewControllerAsSheet:loginViewController];
```

Pretty basic and it works great, however when I Archive the app and distribute the app from Xcode Organizer, the presentation never happens.

It doesn't matter if I distribute the app with our without signing.
Following the system logs, I can see that the `loginViewController` is a valid object but it's followed by 2 lines that simply say `<private>`

[image]

I've tried changing the code to:

```
[self presentViewControllerAsModalWindow:loginViewController];
```

and i've also tried using a storyboard segue but the same thing happens.

Has anyone encountered this before?

Comment: Try sudo log config --mode "private_data:on" if you need those private logs https://twitter.com/sethwillits/status/791744004329132033 Don't forget to post result.

Comment: Thats awesome, thanks. So now I see the problem. `*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:]: cannot decode object of class (WKWebView) for key (NS.objects); the class may be defined in source code or a library that is not linked`

Comment: I put it as an answer, seems helpful :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reveal private redacted log message within Console.app one can use command:

```
sudo log config --mode "private_data:on"
```

Comment: Thanks. I would have never found the issue without that! Seems I needed to add the `WebKit` framework to the project. And here's me thinking that was meant to be automatic when you use `@import WebKit;`

Comment: I didn't know the command as well. Have found it last weekend while watching some WWDC videos that asked people to post interesting cocoa dev tips. There is a hashtag on twitter for it (#cocoatip #wwdc17) . Have already turned it on as well.